# how to convert 16 bit R G B value to 8 Bit R G B value in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have RGB array it is in uint16 example:

```
l.r(1) = 63736
```

How do i change this to 8 bit  (255) format

I tried uint8(l.r(1)) but this gave wrong result.

Answer (score 5):

You need to rescale it also:

```
l.r(1) = 63736;
uint8(l.r ./ 2^8);
```

If you have the image processing toolkit, you can use im2uint8:

```
RGB1 = imread('image.png');
RGB2 = im2uint8(RGB1)
```